# Definition of a powersmooth number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, coprime

I understand the basic definition of a smooth & powersmooth number.

- Let $B$ be an integer. An integer $N$ is called **$B$-smooth** if every prime factor $p$ of $N$ is less than $B$
  $N = 2^{78} · 3^{89} · 11^3$  is called as a $12$-smooth number
- A number is said to be $B$-powersmooth if every prime power dividing $N$  is less than $B$.
  $N = 2^5 · 3^3$ is $33$-powersmooth (the biggest prime power is $2^5$ which is 32)

I also found a different defintion of powersmooth

- An integer $N$ is said to be $B$-powersmooth if it is a product of coprime numbers less than $B$.

I am unable to understand this definition. Can someone give an example for this & how it co-relates with the other definition?

Comment: $N = 32\cdot 27$ is $33$-powersmooth because $32$ and $27$ are coprime and they are less than $33$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Suppose $N=3\cdot 10$, then $N$ is 6-powersmooth according to first definition but not according to second definition.

Comment: @Asher2211 What is $B$ in your example?

Comment: $30$ is also $2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ and these are all coprime and less than $6$.

Comment: @Asher2211 how is 10 less than 6?

Comment: $10$ is not less than $6$ but I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri $10$ is coprime to $3$ so using second definition it is not 6-powersmooth

Comment: The second definition is: "There exists a way to write $N$ as a product of coprime numbers less than $B$". This is *not* the same as "For every way of writing $N$ as a product of coprime numbers, those numbers are less than $B$". Notice that in general a number can be written as the product of coprime numbers in more than one way.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri - Is there a way to relate the 2 definitions

Comment: $10$ isn't less than $6$. The definition is, in my opinion, poorly worded. Basically, $N$ is $B$-powersmooth if you *can write* a product of coprime numbers less than $B$. Thing is, if a number is $B$-powersmooth, then it is *also* $(B+z)$-powersmooth for any positive integer $z$. So $30$ is $11$-powersmooth because you can write it as $10 \cdot 3$. It is *also* $6$-powersmooth because you can write it as $2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.

Comment: The $2$ definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri - is there a way to prove one definition if you assume that the other is true?

Comment: Yes. But you should focus on *understanding* the second definition; it seems you are still confused by the "there is" versus "for all".

Comment: @Fimpellizieri - i do understand the definition now. But I am interested in knowing how one defn leads to the other & the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to put this in an actual answer. First: a number that is $B$-powersmooth is also $(B+z)$-powersmooth for any positive integer $z$. (Also true for smooth.)

For instance, your first example, $2^5 \cdot 3^3$ is $33$-powersmooth, because $2^5 < 33$ and $3^3 < 33$. But $32$ and $27$ are also both less than, say, $53$, and $175$, and $2021$. So $864$ is $33$-powersmooth, but is also $2021$-powersmooth and $10^{1000}$-powersmooth.

The issue here is that we want to find the *lowest* possible $B$, in general.

The second definition you give is "An integer $N$ is said to be $B$-powersmooth if it is a product of coprime numbers less than $B$." That is:

$$(N = abc\cdots Q) \land (a < b < c < \cdots < Q) \land (a,b,c,\cdots Q) = 1 \implies N \text{ is } (Q+1)\text{-powersmooth}$$

Since we only really care about the *smallest* possible $B$, it makes sense to find the product of the smallest possible coprime integers. Those smallest coprime integers will be the individual terms in the prime factorization $N = \prod p_i^{a_i}$.

This is essentially the same as the first definition; it's just that the first definition is a lot more explicit.

Edit to add: The first definition is:

$$(N = \prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}) \land (B > p_1^{a_1}, B > p_2^{a_2}, \dots B > p_k^{a_k}) \implies N \text{ is } B \text{-powersmooth}$$

But we can rewrite the prime-power factorization as $N = abc \cdots B$. WLOG, we can order the prime powers by size so that $p_1^{a_1} < p_2^{a_2} < \cdots < p_k^{a_k} < B$. And since the terms are all prime powers, we know they're coprime: $(p_1^{a_1}, p_2^{a_2}, \dots p_k^{a_k}) = 1$. Hopefully you see how these can be directly substituted into the second definition as I wrote it above.

Comment: Thank you. You can also define Smooth similarly, right? "An integer N is said to be B-smooth if it is a product of powers of coprime numbers less than B"

Comment: Right. It's just that normally if we talk about this kind of smoothness, the only *interesting* $B$ is the smallest one. I think the second definition really ought to be "can be written as a product of coprime numbers $< B$"